# How to toggle sidenav component from header component using a button

Tags: css, angular, sidenav

Hello I am using angular 8 and I want to toggle sidenav component on mobile view. So on mobile media query I am using this CSS to hide the sidenav

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.sidenav {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
}
```

So on mobile view I have a hamburger icon on header component . So on clicking how can I toggle sidenav component ?

**Header HTML:-**

```
<div class="header">
  <fa-icon class="hamburger" [icon]="faBars"></fa-icon>

 <div class="logo-section">
  <img class="logo" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" src="../../../assets/images/abc.png"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Header Component:-**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  searchText: string;

  faBars = faBars;

  constructor(private route: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Sidennav HTML :-**

```
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="logo">
        <!-- 
        <img src="../../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="SKS" /> -->
    </div>
    <div class="sidenavbar">

        <div class="menu" appMenuactive [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['selected']">
            <p class="menuicons">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faTh"></fa-icon>
            </p><span>
                Dashboard
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="menu" appMenuactive [routerLink]="['/data']" [routerLinkActive]="['dataselect']">
            <p class="menuicons">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faTachometerAlt"></fa-icon>
            </p><span>
                Info
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="menu" appMenuactive [routerLink]="['/storage']" [routerLinkActive]="['dataselect']">
            <p class="menuicons">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faStar"></fa-icon>
            </p><span>
                Storage
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Sidenav Component :-**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  faTachometerAlt = faTachometerAlt;
  faTh = faTh;
  faStar = faStar;
  constructor() { }
  activatemenu = false;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

How can I make navbar visible on clicking of header fa-icon  in mobile view ?

Comment: You need to send information from component to another. for that you should use Observable and Subject -> [Tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: @RomanŠimík what kind of information need to be send in this case ?

Comment: @NoobCoder Don't you want `<sidenav-component>` to be in `header.component.html` ?

Comment: @Emilien If sidenav and header was in same component then there was no issue. But I have different component for sidenav and header.

Comment: @NoobCoder Then like Roman said, you just need to implement a service which will store the value. You can use Subject it would be easy.

Comment: @Emilien Is there any example related to this ? And what kind of value need to be store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post it as an answer but normally, you have all you need on [this link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) (Thanks @Roman Šimík).

Make a service like :

```js
export class HeaderService {

  isDisplayed = false;
  private showSideNavSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  toggle(): void {
    this.isDisplayed = !this.isDisplayed;
    this.showSideNavSubject.next(this.isDisplayed);
  }

  get(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.showSideNavSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**Header**

```html
<fa-icon class="hamburger" [icon]="faBars" (click)="toggle()"></fa-icon>
```

```js
constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {}

toggle() {
  this.headerService.toggle();
}
```

**Sidenav**

```html
<p>Show sidenav : {{ showSideNav }}</p>
```

```js
showSideNav = false;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.headerService.get().subscribe(sideNav => this.showSideNav = sideNav);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I implement it on a Stackblitz but without a router. It's working.
Is this what you need ?

Comment: @NoobCoder Here's [my StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuucyw). I've brought some modifications but you can go further

Comment: Ok , but I didn't get how you are linking boolean with html. In my case how can I make hide/show using boolean ? As you can see my navbar div.

Comment: @NoobCoder You mean this ? `<p *ngIf="showSideNav">Show sidenav : {{ showSideNav }}</p>`

Comment: Yes , how will I define true and false value with show and hide for the entire `sidenav` div.

Comment: I don't understand your problem ... Where in your code do you call your sidenav component ?